# Android TextView's stopped wrapping text

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, word-wrap

I spent a ton of time looking for a solution to this but have not found anything that seems similar to what I am experiencing. When I run my app on my G2 none of my textviews wrap text.(regardless of how large the views are.) If i run it on an emulator they wrap appropriately. None of my other apps seem to have this problem when deployed to my G2. I have power cycled my devices, recreated layouts, etc. This seems to even affect a standard alert dialog in this particular app. It is happening in all my activities. Has anyone seen anything like this or does anyone have an idea what I should be looking at?

Some code as requested...

```
AlertDialog.Builder eula = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
            .setTitle(R.string.eula_title)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .setMessage(R.string.eula_text)
            .setCancelable(accepted)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.eula_accept,
                        new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                setAcceptedEula(activity);
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                mHandler.post(mSplashScreen.launch);
                            }
                        })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.eula_decline,
                        new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                                activity.finish();
                            }
                        });
    eula.show();
```

Standard alert dialog won't wrap text. It shows one line that trails off the view.

Comment: Please post the relevant code you have got so it will be easier to find out what's not right?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK so i figured it out.
I have a theme applied to my app with parent theme `Theme.Holo`.

When I removed that theme as the parent my `textviews` started wrapping again! I don't know why other then when run on a device that doesn't understand `Theme.Holo` it got confused.

So I just created an additional `values-v13` directory and modified my themes. Sorry for the trouble folks.

Comment: I don't think that is a satisfying solution. The holo theme should still wrap text when run on devices < 3.0.

Comment: Actually it makes a lot of sense... You can not assume that an older OS can understand something from a future OS. So to a device running 2.2 it does not have a value for Theme.Holo so it applies an empty theme with no properties at all, and because I had it set as the parent theme for the app it messed up every text view in the app.

Comment: Confirmed. I think this is a bug in Holo theme. I just set android:maxLines attribute to 1000000... and text frapping works on Holo theme too.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Larry McKenzie answer I had to set corresponding parameters to the TextView:

```
android:ellipsize="none"
android:maxLines="20"
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
android:singleLine="false"
```

Example:

```
<TextView                  
  android:textColor="@color/white"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:ellipsize="none"
  android:maxLines="20"
  android:scrollHorizontally="false"
  android:singleLine="false"
  android:text="@string/my_text" />
```