# Android: AlertDialog Message does not wrap automatically on SDK < 11

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm having an issue with an `AlertDialog` I built programmatically: Its message shows up correctly in my emulator running 4.1.2. But on my Device (a Huawei U8510 running 2.3.7) the message does not automatically wrap.

Is there anything I can add to the code so the AlertDialog will allow its message to wrap? I obviously don't want to add manual line breaks. (The thing is, even when I add manual line breaks, the Dialog will only show the first line)

I guess I'm just missing something here, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere – they all refer to manually adding line breaks.

Here's the relevant code (Yes, I'm using hard-coded stings for now):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder( activity );
builder.setPositiveButton( ...
builder.setNegativeButton( ...
builder.setTitle( "Wirklich löschen?" );
builder.setMessage( "Soll das Item \"" + deleteItem + "\" wirklich gelöscht werden?" );
AlertDialog dialog= builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

And here are the screenshots. You can see how the message wraps correctly on the Emulator (large image) but not on the device.

[image: Device (2.3.7)]

[image: Emulator (4.1.2)]

Comment: I think you mean 'wrap' instead of 'break'...

Comment: exactly, thanks. i edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what is the problem or whether it is device specific or what but I can suggest a work around for this situation..you can create a custom layout with a textview and two buttons at the bottom and attach that layout to this dialog. Now you can handle your textview as you want...

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this problem in a project that was moved from Android Studio back to Eclipse.

In this situation the problem was a minSdkVersion was not defined.  If you do not declare this attribute, the system assumes a default value of "1", which indicates that your application is compatible with all versions of Android.

Evidently API Level 1 (which is even earlier than Cupcake 1.5)  did not wrap AlertDialog message text.

The problem was solved by adding

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
```

to the Android Manifest.  An minSdkVersion of 16 (Jelly Bean) is what was required for this application.  I don't know when AlertDialog started wrapping message text, but earlier API levels e.g. 10 (Gingerbread) might also work.

On a separate note, others have found using Theme.Holo on earlier versions of Android can cause this problem, e.g.  [Android TextView's stopped wrapping text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922671/android-textviews-stopped-wrapping-text)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a consistent look and feel across all Android versions, you should consider using a custom layout.

In this case a simple `TextView` should do the job. You can style, align and modify the text appearance to match whatever you need.

**custom_dialog.xml**:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/custom_dialog_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Then use the following method to apply it to your dialog:

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
```